# Callout click is not working in iPhone simulator 4s in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, annotations, callout

I have created annotation view over current latitude and longitude and used image over it using custom annotation. It works fine and created custom callout using Apple example MapCallout
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html
[used flag portion to set image and click portion from purple pin notation ] but my click is working fine in iPhone simulator 5 and later but click not working in iPhone 4S simulator over callout, I have tried by many ways but did not get success. Can any one suggest what I have missed to set for iPhone 4s to run click over callout.

My Code is as follows in view Annotation,

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *returnedAnnotationView = nil;

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MAKRSampleAnnotation class]])
    {
        returnedAnnotationView = [MAKRSampleAnnotation createViewAnnotationForMapView:self.mapView annotation:annotation];

        // provide the annotation view's image
        returnedAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pointer_yellow.png"];

        // trying to click using this in 4s , working in iPhone 5 and later
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        ((MKPinAnnotationView *)returnedAnnotationView).rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        return returnedAnnotationView;
    }

    return returnedAnnotationView;
}
```

I have spent much time to fix this but not get luck to make it out.

Thanks.

Comment: OMG! one view was interrupting on click. Removed and fixed.